# How to make custom control preview designer friendly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In Asp.Net I have made a custom user control to handle an auto-completing text box.

This consists of a HiddenField, a TextBox, and an AutoComplete extender.
(there are also a few script tags but those are *irrelevant* to this post)

The issue I'm having is that when i use this control, the designer renders each control within it. This looks very sloppy, as seen in the picture below.

Is there any way to define how the custom user control should render in the designer?

Ideally it would render without displaying the HiddenField and AutoComleteExtender.

[image]

Here is the code from the generic controls.

`<asp:HiddenField ID="IdBox" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
<asp:TextBox ID="DisplayBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoExtender" runat="server" </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>`

Comment: Share the code to create the control.

Comment: @RezaAghaei The elements were just drag and dropped from the designer into the control.